# KnockoutJS Remove dynamic bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've managed to get a prototype working with the help of others to dynamically add new inputs and next to it that specific inputs settings. However I've been trying to get to grips how to remove what I've added dynamically. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="input-row" data-bind="foreach: inputItems">                 
    <div class="input-row-item">                
        <div>   
            <label data-bind="text: label"></label>                 
            <input data-bind="attr:{ name: name, placeholder: placeholder, disabled: disabled() === 'true', value: value, type: type }">                    
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: label" placeholder="input label">
            <input type="text" value="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: type" placeholder="input type">
            <input type="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: name" placeholder="input name">
            <input type="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: placeholder" placeholder="input placeholder">
            <input type="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: disabled" placeholder="input disabled">
            <input type="text" class="nb-remove" data-bind="value: value" placeholder="input value">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: removeInput">Remove this</button>
        </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

THE JS

```
$(function(){
    var InputItem = function InputItem(label, type, name, placeholder, disabled, value) {
        this.label          = ko.observable(label);
        this.type           = ko.observable(type);
        this.name           = ko.observable(name);
        this.placeholder    = ko.observable(placeholder);
        this.disabled       = ko.observable(disabled);
        this.value          = ko.observable(value);
    }

    var ViewModel = function ViewModel() {
      var that = this;

      this.inputItems = ko.observableArray([]);          

      this.addInput = function addInput() {
        that.inputItems.push(new InputItem());
      };

      this.removeInput = function removeInput(){
        //remove input here
      }

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

Comment: you should add dinamically inputs with ids and f.e. ```id="dyn-input-i"``` where ```i``` is a number. So you can managed this inputs for removing in your code

Comment: simple `anno` you just need to try like this `that.removeInput = function (item){that.inputItems.remove(item)}` . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this

**View Model:**

```
         var ViewModel = function() {
              var that = this;
              that.inputItems = ko.observableArray([new InputItem()]);  
              that.addInput = function () {
                that.inputItems.push(new InputItem());
              };

              that.removeInput = function (item){
                that.inputItems.remove(item);
              }
            }
         ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X3NWm/39/)**

*Few Suggestions:*

1) As you assigned `var that=this` you try to use `that` consistently across vm

2) You can create a function name simply like this `var fun=function()` else you can just do like this `function fun(){//blah blah}`